# Does standard SQL allow grouping of union expressions?

Tags: sql, union, language-lawyer, operator-precedence, parentheses

I glanced at the SQL-92 standard, then at a SQL-92 grammar somebody put together but couldn't understand much.

As the [SQL Server documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191141%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) reminds us, there are cases where the expressions should be explicitly grouped:

> By default, SQL
>   Server 2005 evaluates a statement that contains UNION operators from
>   left to right. Use parentheses to specify the order of evaluation. For
>   example, the following statements are not equivalent:

```
/* First statement. */
SELECT * FROM TableA
UNION ALL
(   SELECT * FROM TableB
   UNION
   SELECT * FROM TableC
)
GO

/* Second statement. */
(SELECT * FROM TableA
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM TableB
)
UNION
SELECT * FROM TableC)
GO
```

> In the first statement, duplicates are eliminated in the union between
>   TableB and TableC. In the union between that set and TableA,
>   duplicates are not eliminated. In the second statement, duplicates are
>   included in the union between TableA and TableB, but are eliminated in
>   the subsequent union with TableC. ALL has no effect on the final
>   result of this expression.

But I have found that MySQL and SqlLite do not support it (for reference, Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres and DB2 do.)

So how can I check if the specs allow it or not?

Comment: What exactly is it that MySQL and SqlLite don't support?

Comment: Formula like `SELECT * FROM p UNION (SELECT * FROM p UNION SELECT * FROM p)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excerpt from [the SQL-92 grammar](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-92.bnf.html), extracted from the SQL-92 standard and hyperlinked:

```
<direct select statement: multiple rows>    ::=   <query expression> [ <order by clause> ]

<query expression>    ::=   <non-join query expression> | <joined table>

<non-join query expression>    ::= 
         <non-join query term>
     |     <query expression>  UNION  [  ALL  ] [ <corresponding spec> ] <query term>
     |     <query expression>  EXCEPT  [  ALL  ] [ <corresponding spec> ] <query term>

<joined table>    ::= 
         <cross join>
     | <qualified join>
     | <left paren> <joined table> <right paren>

<non-join query term>    ::= 
         <non-join query primary>
     |     <query term>  INTERSECT  [  ALL  ] [ <corresponding spec> ] <query primary>

<query term>    ::=   <non-join query term> | <joined table>

<cross join>    ::= 
         <table reference>  CROSS  JOIN <table reference>

<qualified join>    ::= 
         <table reference> [  NATURAL  ] [ <join type> ]  JOIN <table reference> [ <join specification> ]

<non-join query primary>    ::=   <simple table> | <left paren> <non-join query expression> <right paren>

<query primary>    ::=   <non-join query primary> | <joined table>

<table reference>    ::= 
         <table name> [ <correlation specification> ]
     | <derived table> <correlation specification>
     | <joined table>

<simple table>    ::= 
         <query specification>
     |     <table value constructor>
     |     <explicit table>

<query specification>    ::= 
          SELECT  [ <set quantifier> ] <select list> <table expression>

<table expression>    ::= 
         <from clause>
         [ <where clause> ]
         [ <group by clause> ]
         [ <having clause> ]
```

<direct select statement: multiple rows> is the rule we will be matching against.
We check that

`SELECT * FROM p` matches <query specification>, <simple table>, <non-join query primary>, <non-join query term>, <non-join query expression>, <query expression>

`SELECT * FROM p UNION SELECT * FROM q` matches <non-join query expression>

`(SELECT * FROM p UNION SELECT * FROM q)` matches <non-join query primary>, <non-join query term>, <non-join query expression>, <query expression>

`(SELECT * FROM p UNION SELECT * FROM q) UNION SELECT * FROM r` now matches <non-join query expression> and <query expression>.

Thus it matches <direct select statement: multiple rows>, so it is a valid SQL-92 statement.

Analogously, `SELECT * FROM p UNION (SELECT * FROM q UNION SELECT * FROM r)`, `(SELECT * FROM p)`, `(SELECT * FROM p UNION SELECT * FROM q)` and even `p CROSS JOIN q` are valid SQL-92 select statements.